# Converting a number string to a number?

Tags: javascript

I have a number string:

```
$1,000,000
```

Is there an easy way to convert it to a number figure soit can be worked with as a number.

```
1000000
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are countless examples and duplicates for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ node
> parseInt('$1,000,000'.replace(/,|\$/g,''))
1000000
```